# How to call a function in another in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I have a function (a function that triggers on click) which I need to call every time when the page is loaded and for that I followed the below code:

```
        callFunction();
        function callFunction(){
           $scope.onClickModel();
        }
        $scope.onClickModel = function (data) {
           alert('Hi')
        };
```

The problem here is when I run the code, I get an error at line 3 saying $scope.onClickModel(); is not a function. Can anyone find out the error here and help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle with your code. The part you've added in your question is not enough.

Comment: No hoisting. Put the last function first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your functions

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.onClickModel = function() {
    alert('Hi');
  };
  
  callFunction();

  function callFunction() {
    $scope.onClickModel();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  Weedoze ,how to call a function if it is like this

Comment: $scope.supportAfterLogin();       $scope.supportAfterLogin = function(){///////}

Answer (score 0):

Please try to define functions before calling it.

```
$scope.onClickModel = function (data) {
   alert('Hi')
};

function callFunction(){
 $scope.onClickModel();
}

callFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this order and pass the parameter to the function without fail

```
    $scope.onClickModel = function (data) {
       alert('Hi')
    };
    function callFunction(){
     $scope.onClickModel("EmptyData");
    }       
   callFunction();
```